# lftp file configuration and stored password

Tags: lftp

I am connecting to some ftp server with lftp.

```
lftp -u login,password -e "ls /someFolderOnTheServer" bla.node.org"
```

Does someone know how I can setup things such that the login and the 
password are read from some configuration file instead ?

many thanks for your valuable help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. Use ~/.netrc file.

Comment: Hi, indeed this is what I tried first, but it does not seem to work in my case. Could it well be because of the fact that the FTP server is secured. the URL name is sftp://bla.node.org. I believe the .netrc is simply ignored here. I tried to get some extensive debug info, by setting debug 3 in the .lftprc file but it does not really work.

Comment: You have to specify the user name in the URL and lftp will pick the password from netrc. The default user name is only used when you don't specify the protocol.

Comment: Hi Lav, I gave it a try and still, it seems to be ignored. Note that the login is my email address Nabil.G@bla.org. Of course, I tried to use the "%40" for @, but still, it fails.Do you have any suggestion which could help? thanks in advance